# Mounting point second hdd, only for additional storage

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, mountpoint

I have searched a lot but I didn´t really find an answer.

I want to do a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 on a new Laptop. It has an SSD and an additional 500GB HDD. In daily usage I don´t want to use the HDD. It´s only for less important big files that I don´t need that often. Normally everything should be installed and stored on the SSD!

Which mounting point do I choose during Ubuntu-installation? The HDD should be mounted automatically at startup.

Or do I have to mess around with fstab after installation?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You have to mess around with fstab after installation. Search for the wiki article on adding a new hard drive.

Comment: Yes, seems like there is no other way -.- It doesn´t work by default...

Answer (score 2):

During installation, you will be asked where you want to install Ubuntu. You can choose the SSD drive and specify that you want the whole drive to be used. A bit will be set apart for swapping though.

After installation is successful, the HDD will automatically be mounted in /media/{some long drive id}. If you want to change the HDD mount point to something easier to remember, then you will need to mess around with the fstab.